# SQLDatabase: Read a lot of data at once and process in memory or read the data when I need it?

Tags: c#, database, sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.
I require a big chunk of data records from the SQL server. This chunk is based on variables, so I don't know before what records I need.
I need to do a large series of calculations and each calculation requires one (or more) records from this chunk of data. Again: I do not know which records are required.

Should I:

A. Load this data into the application memory all at once

- This creates a single connection to the DB, loads ALL required data by a query command (and a forward only DataReader) and then doesn't bother the SQL server anymore.
- The datafetch seems to be slow, since it's reading hundred of thousands of lines into memory

B. Whenever the calculation needs data, retrieve it from the database

- This would open and close a connection to the SQL db multiple times per second.
- The initial datafetch is reduced to only a few miliseconds, but creates a massive load on the SQL server during calculation.

Comment: Connections to SQL Server come from a cache pool. Subsequent connections are not necessarily slow.  Without more information, it's hard to say which is best, though it would be easy enough to try both approaches and see which one performs better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey perhaps not slower, but you still need to be pulling data across the line, which is slower than just doing a selection on the in-memory data?

Comment: Without any information about data amount/size this question is hard to answer.

Comment: My solution to this was a hybrid: instead of pulling 100.000 lines from the databases at the same time or pulling 1 line a lot of times I pull blocks of 1000 lines at once which gave the best improvement. Beware though, any solution is extremely dependant on what situation you're in.

Comment: If (external) data changes are rare and it isn't an issue to pick them up until later, then you could use option B with caching: Read a record once from the database and serve it from the cache for the next minute.

Comment: Pieter & Bart: great tips! I must try those whenever I get the opportunity.

Comment: @Recipe also make sure to **really** pull large numers of records at the **same** time and not go through a resultset where you're basically still pulling 1 line at the time with all of the overhead that goes with it. Look into things like **rowsetsize** .

Comment: @PieterB I think that's also a mistake we need to fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you can turn your whole calculation in to an SQL query (or a series of queries or a stored procedure) then do so. Databases are good at this stuff, and you or a DBA may be able to do a lot to improve the query if it's still too slow.

If not:

- Use a connection pool. Not doing so is usually crazy, unless you're writing a script that only connects once or twice.
- If you're testing this in a development environment with a local DB, beware that there can be a big difference in performance characteristics compared to a production one and don't over-optimize based on what you measure. Network delays in particular could catch you out. Fetching one row at a time may be fine with a low network latency, and awful with a high one.
- Database sizes are usually bigger in production, and go up over time. If you fetch all the data in advance you could get caught out and run out of memory (unless you know more about your data then we do...).
- As Pieter B suggests, you're probably better fetching data in batches if you really need a large number of rows. Then you'll neither blow everything else out of your server's memory, nor have a network latency and query overhead on every row. It'll also help if you want to report progress to the user.
- If you're *really* serious about making it go as fast as possible and not using SQL to do it, then you could try parallelizing your code. Then you can be calculating with one set of data whilst fetching the next, and if your production DB has multiple cores and disks you can parallelize in the DB, too. You could also look at caching, if that's appropriate (memcached and similar, or directly in your server if you know your data sizes well enough).